# Change the tense in this sentence

Tags: tense

Here is my sentence. I want to know if I use the tenses correctly.
Bolds are confusing me.

> I want to change my life, **starting** at **stop** doing ...

Comment: What is the sentence meant to say?

Comment: More common phrases would be "starting by..." or "starting with...". For example, "I want to change my life, starting by giving up drinking".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your use of the ellipsis correctly, you're giving a fragment of your intended sentence, not a complete sentence. (People sometimes pace an ellipsis at the end of a grammatically complete sentence that nevertheless leaves something unsaid, but I assume that's not how you meant it.)

Therefore I'll assume you're trying to construct a sentence that's something like the following. I'll use this extended version as an example, for the sake of clarity.

> I want to change my life, starting at stop doing things because of peer pressure.

The sentence above does not have correct grammar. It should be something like:

> I want to change my life, starting with stopping doing things because of peer pressure.

"Starting at" can be used when those words are followed by a place or time, but here you're not starting at a place, you're starting *with* an activity.

The activity here has to act as a noun, but "stop doing things because of peer pressure" would be a verb phrase. What you need is a gerund phrase, therefore the gerund "stopping" is used.

Just as a style matter, the "starting with stopping doing" sounds very awkward, both because of the combination of "starting" and "stopping" and the chain of "-ing"s. I'd recommend instead something like:

> I want to change my life, starting with no longer doing things because of peer pressure.

Comment: Thanks, suggestion sentence is very helpful. In this case, starting with/by are same?

Comment: From the comment in my question, does **starting by giving up drinking** also sound weird?

Comment: "I want to change my life, starting with giving up drinking" sounds better to me. If you want to use "by" instead, I would break it up into "I want to change my life; I'll start by giving up drinking."